# how to represent complement of a character(eg A bar) in java

Tags: java

I am creating a project "test" Which takes questions set by teacher and student has to answer them.What if teacher has to set boolean expression questions The question appear in label in swing.That is why I have told swing That is why I want to know how to represent A bar(complement of A) in label in frame.is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is `|A` what you are looking for?  E.g.: `System.out.println("|A");`?

Comment: **Please don't repost your questions**. Improve your original one: [how to represent complement of a character in swing in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26159531). It will get reopened if you improve it sufficiently. Take notice of my comment beneath your original question.

Comment: This is a repost of a previous asked (and closed) question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to represent complement of a character in swing in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159531/how-to-represent-complement-of-a-character-in-swing-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unicode, the numbering of all kind of characters in the World. Under Windows or Linux there is a char map utility which which to look after characters:

You will find `U+XXXX` codes show, where `XXXX` is a hexadecimal number (base 16: 0-9A-F).
You can use this number in Java as `\uXXXX`.

```
Ā = "\u0100"     U+0100
ā = "\u0101"     U+0101
```

The bar, also called macron, also exists separately as "combining diacritical mark", a zero-width accent:

```
̄   = "\u0304"
```

In Char Map you can find other *combining diacritical marks* by selecting the thus named "Unicode subrange."

Hence

```
Ā  ==  "\u0100"  == "A\u304"
```

However is some fonts that may not look to good. But it would mean little work, to replace *any* letter with its bar-variant. The teacher types in "X-bar" and you replace it.

```
String s = ".... a-bar ... z-bar ...";
s = s.replaceAll("-bar\\b", "\u304");
```

The regex `"\\b"` is a word boundary marker, so you won't translate "milk-bars."

---

Maybe best would be to edit in Unicode, say UTF-8. As `≤ ≠ ≈ ∞` probably are also desired. This means setting the editor and java compiler to use UTF-8. For separate text editing, there exist free NotePad++ and JEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Labels in Swing support HTML, and the *overline* character entity can be used in the HTML:

```
label.setText("<html>A&#773;");
```

See a [HtmlDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) screenshot

[image: HtmlDemo screenshot]

Comment: Or `\u0305`, combining overline, "A\u0305" in java. Advantage of this approach: data entry with simple ASCII.